# How to handle phone rotation for OpenGLView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, opengl-es

Could anyone please advise on the following:

I have a Xamarin app that renders a cube using OpenGLView. Works fine.

In my RenderLoop code I call:

```
Matrix4 projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(m_fieldOfView,
                                                                m_aspectRatio,
                                                                0.1f,
                                                                100.0f);
```

and pass this on into my shader.

m_aspectRatio was calculated at app startup as:

```
m_aspectRatio = (float)m_grid.Children[0].Width / (float)m_grid.Children[0].Height;
```

because my OpenGLView is on a Xamarin grid control as child zero.

I can start the app in portrait or in landscape mode and it works fine, I see the cube nicely centered on the screen - here's the portrait example:

[image]

Now, if I turn the phone to landscape the cube is not longer centered on the screen:

[image]

Can anyone advise what I more I might have to do?

(I tried setting the aspect ratio to it's own reciprocal when the orientation changes but this makes no difference)

Thanks,
Mitch.

Comment: Try following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4.createperspectiveoffcenter?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by recreating the content of the page each time I detect a rotation of the device has occurred and this works very well.

Mitch.